# In symmetric searchable encryption are the algorithms public?

Tags: encryption, symmetric

If a user (other than the data owner) possesses the secret key in symmetric searchable encryption scheme are they able to run the trapdoor algorithm, or is this not publicly available?

Comment: In an academic cryptographic context, any algorithm is assumed public (except in specific domains like code obfuscation); that's the second of [Kerckhoffs's principles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerckhoffs%27s_principle).